# How do I resolve 'ClientSideAppsHelper.RenderScriptConfiguration is obsolete'

Tags: acumatica

Ever since either 18r2 or 19r1, I've been looking at this error when publishing my customization project.  We just upgraded to 19r2, and it has not been resolved yet.  Is this something that Acumatica simply hasn't resolved yet, or did I miss something that I need to update?  If I need to do something, how do I resolve this error message?  I have not found anything on Stack Overflow or simple google searches even referencing this.

```
\MasterPages\FormDetail.master(12): warning CS0612: 'ClientSideAppsHelper.RenderScriptConfiguration()' is obsolete
\MasterPages\FormTab.master(12): warning CS0612: 'ClientSideAppsHelper.RenderScriptConfiguration()' is obsolete
\MasterPages\FormView.master(12): warning CS0612: 'ClientSideAppsHelper.RenderScriptConfiguration()' is obsolete
```

Comment: It's a widespread warning, I never really bothered about it.

Comment: Thanks.  After a year of looking at it, I really wish they would fix it.  Seems to be in the master pages, and I have no idea what the fix is supposed to be.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with it and it's something that doesn't directly affect customization but my intuition tells me this template isn't used at runtime on production website so removing the following from the template files could remove the warning with no negative impacts: '<%= ClientSideAppsHelper.RenderScriptConfiguration() %>'